# FormItem smartgwt reset after a certain moment

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

When I edit a field (for example textItem) without saving and I let it for a certain moment the field reset automatically.
I want to know what we call (technically) this time of inactivation of an application?

I'm working with smartgwt3.0,GWT 2.1.0.
Operating system IE9

Answer (score 0):

You may create a timer. Inside the run method you can do whatever you need to.

```
Timer timer = new Timer() {            
   @Override
   public void run() {
       textItem.clearValue();
   }
};
timer.scheduleRepeating(1000);
```

Remember that the interval is in milliseconds.